# Should I attach my .on('click') event to the document or element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Yesterday I was reading the jQuery docs for `.on()` where was stated:

> Avoid excessive use of document or document.body for delegated events on **large documents**

But today, I was looking at this [JSPERF](http://jsperf.com/on-vs-bind-vs-delegate-vs-native) and I notice a better performance when the click event is attached to the document.

So right now, I'm confused. The performance tests speak against the docs?

Comment: Click event attached to the $link, document is only a listener for event.target

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your JSPerf here is testing the speed to attach events, not the effect that they have on cumulative page performance. This is the wrong thing to test!

Javascript events propagate up the DOM all the way to the document root. This means that if you have an `on("click", ...)` handler on `document`, then *every click* on *every element* in the document will end up running an event handler, so jQuery can test if its origin matches the delegate target, to see if it should be passed to that event handler.

Imagine that your page has 10 different delegated event handlers on document, all handling various clicks. Every time you click any element in the page, the event will bubble up to the document root, and all 10 of those handlers have to be tested to figure out which (if any) should be run.

In general, you want your delegated events to be as deep in the tree as possible while still enabling your functionality, since this limits the number of elements that may invoke this event, and you can handle the event earlier to prevent it from propagating up the DOM tree.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.
You can attach handler to any element you want, of course, and in some cases you will have to attach it to `document` or `body` (if you, for example, want to target *all* the links on the page). But, if you are sure that certain elements will always appear only inside given element (which is already created) - then for performance sake, you can attach event handler to that common parent.

Answer (score 0):

The point is **excessive**.

IMHO **excessive** delegates on any DOM is terrible